# BigQuery table export to json failing in US-Central

Tags: google-cloud-platform

ERROR: (bq)
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an [internalError 500](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#internalError). This error returns when an internal error occurs within BigQuery. You will have to contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) or [file a bug using the BigQuery issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0).